# Plesk admin password for MySQL

Tags: mysql, password

Does anyone know how Plesk stores MySQL admin password? I accidentally changed the admin password in MySQL's user table which was set by Plesk and now Plesk is broken.

Comment: Running on windows or linux?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, the MySQL admin password set by Plesk can be found in `/etc/psa/.psa.shadow`.